# Using JPanel coordinates while drawing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, graphics2d

I'm making simple game in Java and I'm using Swing. I have JFrame and inside it I want to have two JPanels - one for score and so on and second below, for actual game. I read that every JPanel has its own coordinates, so point (0, 0) is on the upper-left corner of that panel.

I override method paintComponent() im my class GameView which displays the game (so it's the second JPanel from these I mentioned). But when I want to draw something in upper-left corner of gameView and set coordinates of that image to (0,0) it draws on BarView.

I read many tutorials and posts about drawing and I don't see what am I doing wrong. So my question is, how to draw something using JPanel coordinates, not JFrame ones? Here's some code:

Adding objects extending JPanel to JFrame:

```
GameView v = new GameView();
    BarView bv = new BarView();
    frame.getContentPane().add(bv);
    frame.getContentPane().add(v);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    v.requestFocus();
    v.repaint();
    bv.repaint();
```

Drawing in JPanel:

```
public class GameView extends JPanel implements View, Commons{

    public static final int WIDTH=WINDOW_WIDTH, HEIGHT=ARENA_HEIGHT;
    private GameScene gameScene;
    private TexturePaint paint;
    private BufferedImage bi;

    public GameView(){
    addKeyListener(new CustomKeyListener());
    addMouseMotionListener(new CustomMouseListener());
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, ARENA_HEIGHT);
    setFocusable(true);
    try {
        bi = ImageIO.read(new File("src/res/texture.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     this.paint = new TexturePaint(bi, new Rectangle(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight()));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {

    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1;
    g.setPaint(paint);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, ARENA_HEIGHT);
    for(Iterator<Drawable> it = gameScene.models.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
    {
        Drawable d = it.next();
        d.draw(g1);
    }
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

    }
```

and method draw of model in gameScene usually looks like this:

```
public void draw(Graphics g1){
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1.create();
    int cx = image.getWidth(null) / 2;
    int cy = image.getHeight(null) / 2;
    g.rotate(rotation, cx+x, cy+y);
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
}
```

Comment: "implements View, Commons": what are these?? mumbojumbo??

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [mcve]. If images are *actually* needed to demonstrate the problem, hot-link to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you haven't specifed a [`LayoutManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for your `frame`, so it will default to [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

When you subsequently call `frame.getContentPane().add(component)` without passing in a position constant, the position `BorderLayout.CENTER` will be defaulted.

The result is that your `GameView` and `BarView` components will be rendered on top of each other.

As a quick test, try specifying the component position as follows:

```
GameView v = new GameView();
BarView bv = new BarView();
frame.getContentPane().add(bv, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
frame.getContentPane().add(v, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

Unless your UI is really simple, you'll probably find that you need to use some other layout manager.  Refer to ['How to Use Various Layout Managers'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html) for more on this subject.